# Помогите решить задачку со списком

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дана непустая последовательность натуральных чисел, за которой следует 0. Вычислить сумму тех из них, порядковые номера которых- числа Фибоначчи.

Вот что есть на данный момент:

```
our_list = []  # заводим пустой список
new_element = 1
while new_element != 0:  # пока в списке не появится элемент "0"
    new_element = int(input())  # считываем очередной элемент
    our_list.append(new_element)  # добавляем его в список
print(our_list)  # выводим список

# ниже Фибоначчи
first_el = 0
second_el = 1
for i in range(len(our_list)):  # выполняем столько раз сколько элементов в списке
    i += 1  # прибавляем 1 к "i"
    first_el, second_el = second_el, first_el + second_el  # меняем местами значение и выполняем сложение
    print(first_el)
```

Comment: в [ряде Фибоначчи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8) две единицы: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5... два раза добавлять второй элемент к сумме?

Comment: Да, в данной ситуации

Comment: @КикОбзор, вы разобрались? а, то у меня тут еще одно решение пришло в мою голову)

Comment: @Дмитрий я был бы не против увидеть еще одно решение). Конечно, если уже не поздно

Comment: @КикОбзор уже забыть успел)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**не верно прочитано условие, решение подходит для обратной задачи и ищет сумму индексов для числ Фибоначчи в списке**

Тут мне кажется удобно было бы сделать проверку: является ли число из списка числом Фибоначчи?

Т. е. можно воспользоваться [формулой Бине](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8#%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5) (фунция от n) и забрать оттуда определение для золотого сечения.
[image: формула]

А, также следствия, что числом Фибоначчи является округление [image: Формула2] и [image: Формула3]

Фунция будет:

```
def is_fib(n):
    phi =  .5 + .5 * math.sqrt(5.0)
    value = phi * n
    return abs(round(value) - value) < 1 / n or n == 0
```

Ну, а затем проверять все числа последовательности и при значении `True` забирать порядковые номера и суммировать

```
result = 0
our_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
for value in our_list:
    if is_fib(value):
        result += our_list.index(value)
print(result)
```

Не забудьте подключить `math`

**Сюда добавлю правильное решение**

Основой стало отказаться от не нужного количества итераций, цикла while и правильность решения.

Итак, будем работать над следующим списком:

```
our_list =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,0]
```

Мы можем отыскать индекс нулевого значения:

```
last_index = our_list.index(0)

>>> last_index
17
```

Следующая функция определяет ближайшее число Фибоначчи к заданному на вход:

```
def reverse_fib(value):
    phi =  .5 + .5 * math.sqrt(5.0)
    if value < 2:
         return value
    return (int(round(log(value * 5 ** .5) / log(phi)))) # phi определено выше

reverse_fib(last_index)

>>> amount_fib = reverse_fib(last_index)
8
```

Напишем рекурсию для нахождения чисел Фибоначчи при заданном количестве членов n:

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

Попробуем:

```
indexes = [fib(i) for i in range(amount_fib)]

>>> indexes
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

А, теперь к нашему списку:

```
result = 0
for k in indexes:
    result += our_list[k]

>>print(result)
41
```

возможно необходимо добавить обработку некоторых крайних значений, но логически вроде правильно

Comment: зачем, если в условии "сумму тех из них, **порядковые номера** которых- числа Фибоначчи"?..  ps `def is_fib(n)` прекрасна, не удаляйте ответ

Comment: добавил комментарий в вверх, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Можно как-то так:

```
first, second = 0, 1

while first < len(our_list):
    print(our_list[first])
    first, second = second, first+second
```

для такого списка:

```
our_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
```

выведет:

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
```

нужно только сумму посчитать:

```
result = 0

while first < len(our_list):
    result += our_list[first]
    # print(our_list[first])
    first, second = second, first+second 
print(result)

33
```